# Transaction with duplicate address in the output

Tags: litecoin

I came across this transaction and noticed that there's duplicate address for the output part.
https://live.blockcypher.com/ltc/tx/ada86c7d6f46f712bfa04982f17ce9cd9d4c2560e3493de9c22f8b135ece6cb9/

When I tested the rpc command "createrawtransaction" to create a transaction that would send to duplicate address in the output, it gave me the error

error code: -8
error message:
Invalid parameter, duplicated address:

Which command to use if I want to send to duplicate address in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command that allows you to do that. While there is no network relay or consensus rule that prevents this, the wallet side has its own rules and will prevent you from doing this as it is largely pointless. If you really want to send to the same address multiple times, you will need to create the transaction bytes manually without the use of any of the RPC commands.